# pcs package not found on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Apt install pcs said that the package cannot be installed on ubuntu 18.04. Package exist, but no compatible version was found.

Comment: there is the package available on Lauchpad https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcs  , download the `.deb` file, and you just need to use `sudo dpkg -i pcs_0.9.164-1_all.deb`

Answer (score 0):

It's in the universe repo. You can switch to that by executing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

You can then install all the available packages the normal way:

```
sudo apt install pcs
```